How does MATLAB's edgetaper function work?
MATLAB has a function edgetaper that does something I haven't seen before:

J = edgetaper(I,PSF) blurs the edges of the input image I using the point spread function PSF.
The output image J is the weighted sum of the original image I and its blurred version. The weighting array, determined by the autocorrelation function of PSF, makes J equal to I in its central region, and equal to the blurred version of I near the edges.
The edgetaper function reduces the ringing effect in image deblurring methods that use the discrete Fourier transform, such as deconvwnr, deconvreg, and deconvlucy.

So this is a form of a window function, but instead of going to 0 near the edges, it blurs the transition at the image edge.
Has anyone used such a window function before? How does it compare to traditional ones like Hamming or Tukey?

The documentation does not specify how the weights are determined, other than saying it's based on the PSF. How could we find these weights? For example, let's assume a Gaussian PSF with a sigma of $\sigma$. The autocorrelation of a Gaussian has a sigma of $\sqrt{2} \sigma$. Maybe the weights are a Gaussian with a sigma of $\sqrt{2} \sigma$ of the distance to the edge?

Here is the Octave implementation of edgetaper:
https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/default/tree/inst/edgetaper.m
It looks like the author doesn’t understand what the MATLAB function does either…

It has been more than 10 years since I have used it.
I will share what I remember, hopefully, it will have some significance.
Assumptions:

Most of MATLAB deconvolution related functions assume the operation will be done in frequency domain without any proper padding.
Basically applying periodic boundary conditions.
The PSF is assumed to be an LPF (Reasonable).
The PSF is assumed to be isotropic. If it is not, it will be approximated as such.

The function edgetaper will calculate its auto correlation in frequency domain. Yet it will approximate it as an isotropic. So think about outer product of 2 1D PSF's.
Since its an LPF the auto correlation will go to zero so you will have a "Top Hat" like function.
This is the mask used to interpolate the image with the PSF applied (In frequency domain, no padding) and the input image.
From my experience, if you apply proper padding, there is no benefit using it.
The Gaussian PSF Case
We'll process 1D PSF into 2D to as the assumption is the PSF is isotropic.
vA = fspecial('gaussian', [256, 1], 10);
vB = ifft(abs(fft(vA)) .^ 2, 'symmetric'); %<! Auto Correlation
minVal = min(vB);
maxVal = max(vB);
vB = (vB - minVal) ./ (maxVal - minVal); %<! Normalize (Linear Scaling [0, 1])
vB = 1 - vB; %<! Inverse proportion
mW = vB * vB'; %<! The Mask (Isotropic)

figure();
image(repmat(mW, 1, 1, 3));
axis('equal');

Remark: One could optimize the code by (Normalization and inversion at once)
vB = (maxVal - vB) ./ (maxVal - minVal);

The output mask is given by:

Pay attention that the Auto Correlation, since is computer by the DFT, is shifted. To match the boundary conditions.

I agree, padding is much better. Window functions are useful for analysis, not so much for filtering.

In the docs there’s an example output. There it looks like the blurry area is a thin border around the image, the sharp part in the middle is a large square. I don’t see how they created that with the autocorrelation of an isotropic PSF. It looks more like the PSF comes in from the edges.

@CrisLuengo, Why? I will update answer to show it.

@CrisLuengo, Anyhow, this is roughly what I remember from it. Probably accurate on the big picture, less on the small details.

Oh, I see now what you mean. Yeah, that certainly looks like it. Thanks!

@CrisLuengo, Indeed, a typo. Fixed it. Thanks.

By the way, this is very different from the Octave implementation, which seems kinda wonky to me (there’s a comment there “I have no clue what Matlab is doing”). Maybe you can submit a PR to Octave?
